# Scheme: Create a procedure product that will ask for two numbers and compute its product

Tags: scheme

Create a procedure product that will ask for two numbers and compute its product. If the product is greater than or equal to 20, your program will ask for a radius in order to compute the area of a circle; otherwise, the program will ask for the length and width to compute the area of a rectangle. If the product is zero, the program will display Invalid Inputs! The program should be implemented in at least two procedures.

help please?
i have this

```
(define circle
  (lambda (radius)
    (* 3.14 (* radius radius)))

(define product
  (lambda (a b)
    (* a b))
```

Comment: is this you're homework?

Comment: Do the same for rectangle and then write the procedure that do side effects (read, display) and use the other procedures according to the description. Are you familiar with let you can make it read likeyour assignment.

Comment: As Sylwester said, it is easy to prompt for input using `read`. For example: `(define a (read))`. You can use `display` or `write` to display output, and `rectangle` is straightforward; just follow your `circle` example.

Answer (score 1):

You can "ask for two numbers" using `read`.

```
> (let ((a (read))) (format "You typed: ~a" a))
12
"You typed: 12"
>
```

That coincidentally show you how to `format` output as well, though a read-through of [the docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html?q=format&q=read#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._format%29%29)  might still help with the finer points. Just remember to check if the return value is actually a number with [`number?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/number-types.html?q=read&q=format&q=read#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._number~3f%29%29), and the rest of your question should be pretty self-explanatory.